# How to link lightbox2 in a table?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox, lightbox2

On my webpage, I have added a table and converted all  into links by using the following code:

HTML- `<tr data-href="../images/accept.png" > <td> Blah Blah </td> </tr>`

JQUERY-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

I want to use lightbox on each of these links such that whenever I click on any row, lightbox opens up. I am using lightbox2 and unable to find a way to do it. 
This is the page for lightbox2: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Lightbox2 requires `data-lightbox="something"`. Did you try adding that to your tr: `<tr data-lightbox="something" data-href="../images/accept.png" > <td> Blah Blah </td> </tr>`

Comment: I did try it. It doesn't work. lightbox specifically looks for <a> tags and I am using <tr> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the lightbox2 page, and it wants you to use an `<a>` tag, so I'd recommend doing that. I don't know this tool very well, but it probably looks specifically for `<a>` tags, so trying to mimic that functionality won't do the trick.

You could try reworking your table layout by wrapping the content of an entire row in an `<a>` tag:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href='#' data-lightbox='test'>
      <div class='col1'>Col1</div>
      <div class='col2'>Col2</div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This would require you to do the 'cell' formatting with styling on your `DIV`s, but you might get it to work.
If you're not married to the table layout, then you've got options. (Also, tables within tables, while a pain in the ass, might do what you want...)

In my experience, don't fight the API / tool you're trying to work with. If you want to use it, figure out a way to use it rather than hacking it. Hacking it can be fun, but will ultimately lead to headaches (especially in production code!!!).